# error while loading shared libraries: libmkl_scalapack_lp64.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: google-colaboratory, quantum-computing

I am using google colab (No GPU) and using 'Quantum Espresso software' on this google colab,

So in the code section: I wrote:

```
! /content/content/q-e/bin/pw.x < 01.vc-relax.in < 01.vc-relax.out
```

got an output like that:

```
/content/content/q-e/bin/pw.x: error while loading shared libraries: 
libmkl_scalapack_lp64.so: cannot open shared object file: 
No such file or directory
```

how to solve this error?

I was trying to get an output file named '01.vc-relax.out' with proper parameters from my given input file '01.vc-relax.in'